How do I display text files with Native JavaScript and HTML
I am making a html page that allows you to upload a txt file for it to read and as long as it is ordered correctly, play it as sound. My problem is that it won't display a text file, at all, and says it can't find said "filepath/file" in the console, where I am printing the text file for testing.
I am unsure on what to do, but any examples of displaying a text file did not seem to be native javascript and/or be not related to html whatsoever. So I am unsure what to do. Code:


const musicstring = new String()

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      musicstring.onload = () => {
        //console.log(ctx.getImageData(0,0,stage.width,stage.height));
        printstring();
      }

      musicstring.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
      printstring();
    }
  });
});

function printstring() {
  console.log(musicstring);
}
<input type='file' accept="text/txt" />



Error shown:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Converted to a snippet.  It doesn't give the error you stated (but also doesn't work)

new String() is not vanilla JS. If you're using an AI to generate code it'd be good to also run a linter/lint tool to help find some of the coding errors it will generate.
